# OpenSLES SLPlaybackRateItf SetRate not working on Android 5.x, but works on Android 4.x

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

OpenSLES SLPlaybackRateItf SetRate works on Android 4.x, but not on Android 5.x.

It seems as if the SetRate interface has no implementation on Android 5.x.

Below are some code snippets, and the complete code can be found here: https://github.com/jimrange/cocos2d-x/blob/audioEngineUpdate/cocos/audio/android/AudioEngine-inl.cpp

```
SLPlaybackRateItf _fdPlayerPlaybackRate;
SLObjectItf _fdPlayerObject;
```

Other initialization code not shown for brevity.

```
// get the playback rate interface
result = (*_fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(_fdPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAYBACKRATE, &_fdPlayerPlaybackRate);
if(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result){ ERRORLOG("get the rate interface failed"); break; }

SLpermille stepSize;
SLuint32 capabilities;
auto rangeResult = (*_fdPlayerPlaybackRate)->GetRateRange(_fdPlayerPlaybackRate, 0, &_minRate, &_maxRate, &stepSize, &capabilities);
if(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != rangeResult)
{
     log("%s error:%u",__func__, rangeResult);
}
```

At this point

_minRate == 500

_maxRate == 2000

stepSize == 0

capabilities == SL_RATEPROP_NOPITCHCORAUDIO

Later when calling the following, the result is SL_RESULT_SUCCESS, but the playback rate does not change.

```
void AudioEngineImpl::setPitch(int audioID,float pitch)
{
    auto& player = _audioPlayers[audioID];

    SLpermille playbackRate = (SLpermille)1000 * pitch;

    if (playbackRate < player._minRate)
    {
        log("Warning: AudioEngine attempting to set rate:%d which is lower than minRate=%d.", playbackRate, player._minRate);
        playbackRate = player._minRate;
    }
    else if (playbackRate > player._maxRate)
    {
        log("Warning: AudioEngine attempting to set rate:%d which is higher than maxRate=%d.", playbackRate, player._maxRate);
        playbackRate = player._maxRate;
    }

    // This works on Android 4.4.4 on Nexus 7, but not on Android 5.x on Nexus 7 or Nexus 9.
    auto result = (*player._fdPlayerPlaybackRate)->SetRate(player._fdPlayerPlaybackRate, playbackRate);
    if(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result)
    {
        log("%s error:%u",__func__, result);
    }
}
```

**Here is what I am experiencing:**

Requesting the SL_IID_PLAYBACKRATE interface returns SL_RESULT_SUCCESS.

I can query the interface for capabilities and I get a range of 500 to 2000, a step size of 0 and a capabilities flag of SL_RATEPROP_NOPITCHCORAUDIO. This is the same on Android 4.x and 5.x.

So the interface is telling me all is setup good and ready to go.

Calling SetRate returns SL_RESULT_SUCCESS on Android 4.x and Android 5.x.

But on 5.x the SetRate does not have any effect on the audio.

There is another SO post that suggests using SL_RATEPROP_PITCHCORAUDIO, but I want to use SL_RATEPROP_NOPITCHCORAUDIO so that there is no pitch correction when changing the rate of the audio. And SL_RATEPROP_NOPITCHCORAUDIO is the default setting, so no need to change that.

From the OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf:

**SL_RATEPROP_NOPITCHCORAUDIO** - Plays audio at the current rate, but without pitch correction.

**SL_RATEPROP_PITCHCORAUDIO** - Plays audio at the current rate, but with pitch correction.

I am working on code to expand the Cocos2d-x AudioEngine.

The Cocos2d-x version is 3.7rc0 and the NDK version is ndk-r10d.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Jim?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I added a bug report to the Android project for OpenSLES SLPlaybackRateItf SetRate not working properly: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186773&thanks=186773&ts=1442506284. Other discussion about this can be found here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/12780

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying though!